# Magento 2 change language for all in Front-end

Tags: store-view, multi-language, language-switcher, stoe-language

I have Magento 2.3.3 I created 3 store views **French**, **English**, and **Turkish**

I need to translate  product descriptions and all Categories is changed the store view. This on the french store. 
On the French Store, I would like to change the Description from English to French. Same problem in all other stores.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please select the your store and add the description

[image]

And add the store wise description your web site.

[image]

Categorys language change the you goes to category tab select the your store

[image]

Any problem let me know

Comment: thanks for your help . it works

Comment: please accept the answer so another community helpful